# How do I convert a Dask Dataframe into a Dask Array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I have a dask dataframe object but would like to have a dask array.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array.html

Answer (score 7):

There are three ways to do this.

1. Use the aptly named [.to_dask_array()](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array) method
2. Use the `.values` attribute, or the `to_records()` method, like with Pandas
3. Use `map_partitions` to call any function that converts a pandas dataframe into a numpy array on all of the partitions

Here is an example doing all three.

```
>>> import dask

>>> df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

>>> df
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   id    name        x        y
npartitions=30                                 
2000-01-01      int64  object  float64  float64
2000-01-02        ...     ...      ...      ...
...               ...     ...      ...      ...
2000-01-30        ...     ...      ...      ...
2000-01-31        ...     ...      ...      ...
Dask Name: make-timeseries, 30 tasks

>>> import numpy as np

>>> df.map_partitions(np.asarray)
dask.array<asarray, shape=(nan, 4), dtype=object, chunksize=(nan, 4)>

>>> df.to_dask_array()
dask.array<array, shape=(nan, 4), dtype=object, chunksize=(nan, 4)>

>>> df.values
dask.array<values, shape=(nan, 4), dtype=object, chunksize=(nan, 4)>

>>> df.to_records()  # note that this returns a record array
dask.array<to_records, shape=(nan,), dtype=(numpy.record, [('timestamp', 'O'), ('id', '<i8'), ('name', 'O'), ('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')]), chunksize=(nan,)

>>> dask.__version__
0.19.0
```

Note that because Dask dataframes don't maintain the number of rows in each chunk, the resulting arrays also won't have this information.  (note the `NaN` values in the shape and chunk size.